# How can I iterate using a single 3 indexed list instead of 3 nested loops?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I am working on a project in Python which requires me to do iteration over a 3-element list as;

```
for i in range(0,10):
 for j in range(0,10):
  for k in range(0,10):
   basis_nums = [i,j,k]
```

Then I use the basis_nums vector for other applications.
However I'd like to do it as follows;

```
iter_list = [1,1,1]

#[2,1,1]
#[3,1,1]
#.
#.
#.
#[9,1,1]
#[1,2,1]
#.
```

etc.
and increase the list elements one by one until its;

```
iter_list = [9,9,9]
```

Any suggestions how I can do it?

Comment: So desired out put is which?

Comment: you mean like specify an alternative start point for your iterations?

Comment: they don't want to use three nested results, 

you can use list comprehension for that, to save the lists in the list or an iterator

Comment: I am trying to generate the permutations in a more compact way instead of many loops which lead to crazy indentations if I wanna extend basis_nums in case.

Comment: `itertools.product` will do what you need - although not in the order you want, but sorting once you have the list should be do-able

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot for answering everyone. <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you mean this:

```
from itertools import product

for basis_nums in product(range(0,10), range(0, 10), range(0, 10)):
    print(basis_nums)
```

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product) saves you the indentation depth. (note: `basis_nums` are `tuples` now and not `lists`).

Comment: that is exactly what I mean. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Or have an extra `repeat=3` at the end:

```
for basis_nums in itertools.product(range(10),repeat=3):
    print(basis_nums)
```

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product) is getting the mathematical product algorithm embedded into python, the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools) module also contains the combination algorithm, as [`itertools.combination`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), also the module contains the permutation algorithm, as [`itertools.permutation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yup, ya took the best one :-), then me adding to it :D, thank you